# Какова точность std::chrono и почему теряются наносекунды

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Здравствуйте,

Есть код который использует функции QueryPerformanceFrequency и QueryPerformanceCounter. Нужно портануть его на UNIX. Хочу рассмотреть std::chrono но мне нужно знать точность std::chrono::high_resolution_clock. Написал простейший тест.

Мой код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

inline void dummy_task();

void WIN_TICKS()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER tBeg;
    LARGE_INTEGER tEnd;
    LARGE_INTEGER tFr;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&tFr);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&tBeg);
    dummy_task();
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&tEnd);

    std::cout << "There are: " << tFr.QuadPart
        << " ticks per second" << std::endl;    
    std::cout << "There are: " << tEnd.QuadPart - tBeg.QuadPart
        << " ticks." << std::endl;    
    std::cout << "There are: "
              << ((double)((tEnd.QuadPart - tBeg.QuadPart) * 1000LL)) / (double)tFr.QuadPart
              << " msec" << std::endl;
}

void CHRONO_TICKS()
{        
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    dummy_task();        
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Time spent: "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
        << " msec" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time spent: "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
        << " usec" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time spent: "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
        << " nsec" << std::endl;
}

inline void dummy_task()
{
    // Disable console output
    std::cout.clear(std::ios::badbit);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "*" << std::endl;
    }

    // Enable console output
    std::cout.clear(std::ios::goodbit);
}

int main()
{
    WIN_TICKS();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    CHRONO_TICKS();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
There are: 3604658 ticks per second
There are: 50 ticks.
There are: 0.0138709 msec

Time spent: 0 msec
Time spent: 0 usec
Time spent: 0 nsec
```

Что интересно:
QueryPerformanceFrequency возвращает 3604658 тиков
chrono::system_clock::period::den возвращает 10000000 тиков. По идее должен быть точнее. (хотя что-то слабо верится в это число)

Как всё таки правильно узнать количество тиков в std::chrono или какая реальная его точность? Почему если мерять время через std::chrono - время теряется?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Количество тиков, которое вам возвращается и точность таймера это разные вещи. Таймер может иметь куда меньшую точность в зависимости от реализации. Например, стандартный сишный clock() имеет частоту от 1000 до 1000000 тиков в секунду на разных компиляторах, при этом его точность составляет около 15 милисекунд, то есть в 15 раз меньше, чем количество тиков в первом слуае и в 15000 раз во втором.

Comment: Наверное я неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Меня интересует какой минимальный отрезок времени я могу этим таймером померять?

Comment: Гарантированно и для разных ОС - 5-15 миллисекунд со страшным джиттером в лучшем случае. А если система нагружена, и того больше.

Comment: Profilers, чтобы более-менее что-то измерять используют драйвера, которые работают на уровне ОС и всё равно их точность в измерительном смысле вряд ли можно определить.